# OUTBOUND_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS not arriving to server side

Tags: java, soap, service, message

I'm calling a service in which I'm setting the OUTBOUND_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS in the following way:

```
 Map<String, DataHandler> attachmentsMap = (Map<String, DataHandler>) context.get(MessageContext.OUTBOUND_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS);
                        ByteArrayDataSource bads = new ByteArrayDataSource(file, PDF_MIME_TYPE);

                        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(bads);

                        AttachmentPart attachmentPart = message.createAttachmentPart();

                        attachmentPart.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(file), PDF_MIME_TYPE);
                        attachmentPart.setContentId(fileId);

                        String contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"" + fileId + "\"";
                        attachmentPart.addMimeHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);

                        message.addAttachmentPart(attachmentPart);

                        attachmentsMap.put(fileId, dh);
```

And on server side I expect to find the same information in the INBOUND_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS but seems that nothing is sent.

Can you please what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I saw that I have to set somehow on AttachmentOutInterceptor the next property: props.put(AttachmentOutInterceptor.WRITE_ATTACHMENTS, Boolean.TRUE). And after that I have to put into JaxWsProxyFactoryBean. But the question is from where should I get JaxWsProxyFactoryBean?

Answer (score 0):

After all I found the solution by myself.

I had to you CXF implementation from Apache and I have to enable the property for writing the attachment.

```
 JaxWsClientFactoryBean clientFactoryBean = new JaxWsClientFactoryBean();
            clientFactoryBean.setServiceClass(DocumentManagementForUnderwritingService.class);
            clientFactoryBean.setAddress(serviceURL);

            JaxWsProxyFactoryBean pfb = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean(clientFactoryBean);
            DocumentUploadHandler.enableSoapClientOutputAttachments(pfb);
            DocumentManagementForUnderwritingService proxyy = (DocumentManagementForUnderwritingService) pfb.create();
```

Below I set the property:

```
 DocumentUploadHandler.enableSoapClientOutputAttachments(pfb);
```

And the method from the handler is:

```
public static void enableSoapClientOutputAttachments(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean pfb){
        Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put(AttachmentOutInterceptor.WRITE_ATTACHMENTS, Boolean.TRUE);
        pfb.setProperties(props);
        pfb.getOutInterceptors().add(new SwAOutInterceptor());
        pfb.getOutInterceptors().add(new AttachmentOutInterceptor());

    }
```

After I created the proxy, I chained the handler:

```
  Binding binding = proxy.getBinding();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        final List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain();
        handlerChain.add(documentUploadHandler);
        binding.setHandlerChain(handlerChain );
```

And the code from the handler is present in the question.
Hope this will help someone else in the future.